# obfucation of logging outputs across all hadler

Tags: python, logging

I have written a simple script with uses the request module,
requests in turn uses urllib3 which emits logs at the DEBUG level where it contains the entire URL [including sensitive components such as api_keys username/passwords etc]

How can I partially modify the log records to obfuscate these sensitive strings

example

without obfuscation the result looks like:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://a.klaviyo.com:443 "GET /api/v1/metrics/timeline?api_key=pk_a1bcfde2bbca1628baceffdcabaebbc221&count=100&sort=asc HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

what I would like it to look like

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://a.klaviyo.com:443 "GET /api/v1/metrics/timeline?api_key=[REDACTED]&count=100&sort=asc HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

since I not have control over the way logging is implemented in other modules is there a way I can even achieve this?

Note I do not have a minimum code example as I do not know where to start

for reference I use streamhandler, filehandler, sockethandler and a custom slackhandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to censor logs is to use a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects). Here's an example that will replace all numbers that are logged with X. You will have to implement your own logic how to find the strings that you want censored.

```
import logging
import re

def myfilter(record):
    record.msg = re.sub(r'[0-9]', 'X', record.msg)
    return True

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addFilter(myfilter)

logger.error('c3nsor th1s str1ng 123 test')
```